# How do I update model in Master detail razor page with AJAX results

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a parent table with rows.
When they select a row, an AJAX call fires that returns the child details.

I have multiple text boxes showing child properties

```
 <div class="row">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Child.Property)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Child.Property)
 </div>
```

but I can't see how to update the text boxes with the child I get back in AJAX results.

The best I've been able to do is manually updating each field from the 'complete' method. But I've got about 30 more fields to add and it feels like the wrong approach.

How do I bind the edit boxes to the returned model without using partials and without refreshing the entire page?

I added Child as a property in the @model, and the TextFor appears to bind properly. But of course

```
 @Model.Child = child
```

does not. So they never show any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was based on a misunderstanding on my part. At first I deleted the question when I realized my mistake. I'm reinstating it because I think it is an easy mistake for a noobie to fall into and once you do, the answer is hard to sort out.

The problem is that @model no longer exists once the page is rendered. There is no data binding going on behind the scenes as I thought there was.

Your options are

1. populating the elements manually. (this will need editing to fit your particular elements)

   ```
    function DisplayMergeSection(data) {
        for (var key of Object.keys(data)) {
            DisplayElement(data, key, "#Clients_");
        }
    }

    function DisplayElement(data, key, prefix) {
        return;
        var val = data[key];
        var valString = data[key + "String"];
        var element = $(prefix + key)[0];
        if (element && element.type === 'text') {
            if ((val || '').toString().indexOf("Date(") > -1) {
                var dtStart = new Date(parseInt(val.substr(6)));
                element.value = moment(dtStart).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            } else {
                element.value = val;
            }
        } else if (element && element.type === 'checkbox') {
            element.checked = val;
        } else if (element && element.type === 'select-one') {
            element.value = valString;
        } else if (element && element.nodeName === 'DIV') {
            if ((val || '').toString().indexOf("Date(") > -1) {
                var dtStart = new Date(parseInt(val.substr(6)));
                element.innerText = moment(dtStart).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            } else {
                element.innerText = val;
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. create a bunch of observables with knockout and then set up data binding. This is a lot cleaner.
   https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html
3. set up a mapping with the knockout plugin.
   https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html